# How can I create a Java enum with associated values like Swift enum?

Tags: java, swift, enums

Edit:
To be clear I am not asking how to do enums in java. I am asking if there is something in java that is complementary to Swifts associated values in enums. This is not just simply how do I store values on enums. Take a look at the example I provided and you will see the difference.

So an iOS developer was showing me an architecture where he used swifts enum associated values. This concept seemed interesting to me I and as an android developer I was curious to see if its possible in java without being overly verbose. What is the equivalent with Java enums? Or is it not possible?

Here is an example of what I mean by Associated Values. Its pulled form the  [apple docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

```
enum Barcode {
    case UPCA(Int, Int, Int, Int)
    case QRCode(String)
}

// Instantiated
var productBarcode = Barcode.UPCA(8, 85909, 51226, 3)
// or
productBarcode = .QRCode("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")


switch productBarcode {
case .UPCA(let numberSystem, let manufacturer, let product, let check):
    println("UPC-A: \(numberSystem), \(manufacturer), \(product), \(check).")
case .QRCode(let productCode):
    println("QR code: \(productCode).")
}
```

Comment: I think something like `Pair<BarCode, Object>` may be what you are looking for.  To give a name with semantic meaning, maybe making something like `BarCodeEntry<T>` which provide a `BarCode getBarCode()` and `T getData()` ?

Comment: @chrylis What your linking to is not the same thing. Take a look at the switch statement. Notice the set of let expressions. In java I am not sure how you can dynamically have each value have a different set of associated values each with a different set of types. The document you linked to does not explain that at all.

Comment: @chrylis did not read the question. I had the same question and found this Q & A to be useful.

Comment: Another example of what I was looking for was what Kotlin calls sealed classes. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html . Its an interesting feature that as far as I know so far java does not have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me with Java enums this will not be possible.

To be close to your posted snippet you would be verbose, as you already assume.

**enum**

```
enum BarcodeType {
    UPCA,
    QRCode,
    UNDEFINED;
}
```

**factory class**

```
abstract class Barcode {

    abstract public BarcodeType getType();

    public static final Barcode newUPCA(int numberSystem, int manufacturer, int product, int check) {
        return new BarcodeUPCA(numberSystem, manufacturer, product, check);
    }

    public static final Barcode newQRCode(String productCode) {
        return new BarcodeQRCode(productCode);
    }
}
```

**concrete implementation UPCA**

```
class BarcodeUPCA extends Barcode {
    private final int numberSystem;
    private final int manufacturer;
    private final int product;
    private final int check;

    public BarcodeUPCA(int numberSystem, int manufacturer, int product, int check) {
        this.numberSystem = numberSystem;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.product = product;
        this.check = check;
    }

    public int getNumberSystem() {
        return numberSystem;
    }

    public int getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public int getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public int getCheck() {
        return check;
    }

    @Override
    public BarcodeType getType() {
        return BarcodeType.UPCA;
    }
}
```

**concrete implementation QRCode**

```
class BarcodeQRCode extends Barcode {

    private final String productCode;

    public BarcodeQRCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    @Override
    public BarcodeType getType() {
        return BarcodeType.QRCode;
    }
}
```

**demo application**

```
public class BarcodeMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Barcode> barcodes = new ArrayList<>();
        barcodes.add(Barcode.newUPCA(8, 85909, 51226, 3));
        barcodes.add(Barcode.newQRCode("foobar"));

        for (Barcode barcode : barcodes) {
            switch (barcode.getType()) {
                case UPCA: {
                    BarcodeUPCA b = (BarcodeUPCA) barcode;
                    System.out.printf("UPC-A: %d, %d, %d, %d%n",
                            b.getNumberSystem(),
                            b.getManufacturer(),
                            b.getProduct(),
                            b.getCheck()
                    );
                    break;
                }
                case QRCode: {
                    BarcodeQRCode b = (BarcodeQRCode) barcode;
                    System.out.printf("QR code: %s%n", b.getProductCode());
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    System.err.println("unhandled type: " + barcode.getType());
            }
        }
}
```

**output**

```
UPC-A: 8, 85909, 51226, 3
QR code: foobar
```

Comment: I Ended up with the exact same Idea, only added casting in the abstract class:  It's more fluent and cleaner since the we check the type with the switch.

 //casting support:
    public BarcodeQRCode asBarcodeQRCode(){
        return (BarcodeQRCode) this;
    }

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with this question, and came up with the following solution. Notably, I don't even use enums, since Java's enums are not well-suited to the task. The important part is that you need `switch`-like behaviour for the cases, with the associated values available in each case.

**enum-like type**

```
public abstract class Barcode
{
    private Barcode() {}

    void caseUPCA(IntFunction<IntFunction<IntFunction<IntConsumer>>> action) {}
    void caseQRCode(Consumer<String> action) {}

    static Barcode UPCA(int numberSystem, int manufacturer, int product, int check)
    {
        return new Barcode()
        {
            @Override public void caseUPCA(IntFunction<IntFunction<IntFunction<IntConsumer>>> action)
            {
                action.apply(numberSystem).apply(manufacturer).apply(product).accept(check);
            }
        };
    }

    static Barcode QRCode(String text)
    {
        return new Barcode()
        {
            @Override public void caseQRCode(Consumer<String> action)
            {
                action.accept(text);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**demo application**

```
public class BarcodeMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        List<Barcode> barcodes = new ArrayList<>();
        barcodes.add(Barcode.UPCA(8, 85909, 51226, 3));
        barcodes.add(Barcode.QRCode("foobar"));

        for(Barcode barcode: barcodes)
        {
            barcode.caseUPCA(numberSystem -> manufacturer -> product -> check ->
                System.out.printf("UPC-A: %d, %d, %d, %d%n", numberSystem, manufacturer, product, check));
            barcode.caseQRCode(productCode ->
                System.out.printf("QR code: %s%n", productCode));
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
UPC-A: 8, 85909, 51226, 3
QR code: foobar
```

**pros**

- Much less implementation code than enum-based solutions
- Even *less* code at usage site than enum-based solutions

**cons**

- Lots of awkward nesting in `Barcode` implementation. Just Java being ugly.
- You can't throw exceptions from the switch case actions.
- Angle bracket blindness in `UPCA` implementation, due to having many arguments. To prevent this leaking into the API, you could declare a `public interface UPCAConsumer extends IntFunction<IntFunction<IntFunction<IntConsumer>>> {}`, and use `UPCAConsumer` for the `caseUPCA(action)` argument type.